# Deserialize json having different format

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have two different type of JSON .Can any one tell how I can deserialize both?

```
{\"SearchResults\": { \"CuisineType\": \"Contemporary American\",   
    \"EarlyPoints\": \"100\"}}

{\"SearchResults\": [ { \"CuisineType\": \"Contemporary American\", 
    \"EarlyPoints\": \"100\"}] }
```

Thanks

Comment: But the format in first line having different format.it gives error when i deserialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example, the value for key `SearchResults` is an **object**.

```
SearchResults = { 
    "CuisineType": "Contemporary American",
    "EarlyPoints": "100"
}
```

Your second example, the value for `SearchResults` is an **array**, with only one array value. That array value contains an *anonymous* object.

```
SearchResults[0] = { 
    "CuisineType": "Contemporary American",
    "EarlyPoints": "100"
}
```